# Failed to install ad-hoc distribution with itunes 11.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, adhoc

I have strange problem. I developed app code signed it with Distribution provisioning profile which includes correct devices and sent it to Client. He installed via iTunes and there were no problems. Suddenly iTunes 11 was released and Client told me that he is unable to install app on his devices.

The situations looks like this:

- authorizing computer
- adding app to iTunes library
- selecting app to sync/install on device
- start synchronization

Synchronization goes to step 4 where message says thet apps to synchronization are prepared and synchronization ends showing in iTunes that app is installed on device. But on device there is no app. No error or any kind of message, nothing...

To make things more complicated I'm able to install app on my devices (I even borrowed iPad's, iPhones and one iPod touch from friends to check it). Although I'm not able to install it on one iPod Touch 4G. The app is compatible with iOS 5 and 6.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar situation to me. iTunes 11 (OSX 10.8) failed to install IPA file. Everything seems all right, but there is no app on device, iPhone4 iOS6.0.1 in this case.

But when I install app via Test Flight, installation works.

When I try to install same application on OSX 10.7, iTunes10, installation works fine.

Maybe is problem in iTunes artwork that has to be 1024x1024, I do not know.

Answer (score 5):

Same issue i was facing, i don't why iTunes 11 has this strange behaviour. But i managed to sent my .ipa to client using, [Diawi](http://diawi.com). You have to upload your .ipa over here and it'll generate a link which will pass to your client and it'll be download easily. So this is simple and nice solution without interacting with iTunes.