# How to install ad hoc provisioning profile on tester device without using iTunes and TestFlight

Tags: ios, testing, installation, itunes, provisioning-profile

Is there a way to to manually install ad hoc provisioning profile on tester device without using iTunes, XCode and apps like TestFlight?

EDIT: I followed the solution suggested by Max and the process of sending the certificate via email seems sensible. However it does not work for me as it says "Invalid certificate".

However it should be valid as I signed the certificate with a correct key (it used to work till last week and will expire only in May 2014). The device uuid entered in the certificate is correct. No idea on how to fix this.

Here is the screenshot taken from the tester device (text is in Italian and says "Invalid profile"):

[image: Invalid profile]

Comment: I tried running iPhone Configuration Utility but in the profiles tab I am unable to install new ones. It only shows installed profiles and allows to remove them. Will try to google a bit more or post a new question specifci to "iPhone Configuration Utility". However I do wonder if there is a bug with iOS 7.0.4  Good thing is that it does not depend on the iPA file as we are purely talking about hte profile that fails to install. So solution should be possible :)

Comment: I had some problems with devices that had provisioning profiles installed with iOS6 and were later upgraded to iOS7. Had to delete the old profiles... And sometimes testers change the device and forget to "mention that tiny detail" to you :)

Comment: Yep.. the testers in this case have definetely upgraded to iOS 7 but the ones with whom I have the issue are the ones that never installed the App before. The testers that upgraded from iOS 6 ot 7 instead seem alright (as they have the old profile installed). I am getting stuck on a wall as all I can really do is to reset everything and try again and again.. will think about this and keep my finger crossed to receive some other solution to try :)

Answer (score 2):

Just send the certificate via email to the device and tap it. Should be installed then if the device is in the devices list of the certificate.

Comment: I tried that way but once the user clicks on the device it says "profile not valid". However it should be valid as I signed the certificate with a correct key (it used to work till last week and will expire only in May 2014). The device uuid entered in the certificate is correct. No idea on how to fix this. For now I upvote the question as it seems a step ahead, will accept once I am sure that there is something else that I am doing that is wrong.

Comment: Try it with one of your own devices, triple check the udid and remove all certificates from the device before trying again. Sometimes signing is a bitch.

Comment: With my own devices seems to work but will try again from scratch.. :) thanks in the meanwhile

Comment: Then this is most certainly a problem with the udid of your clients device.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved. The issue was that the software I was using to get the testers uuid has apparently a bug. [This is a detailed answer on how to solve this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728915/unable-to-install-provisioning-profile-on-ad-hoc-distribution-test-devices-using/20742179#20742179)