# How testflight is resigning with new mobile provisioning profile with out certificate?

Tags: ios, ipa, mobileprovision

I am amazed with test flight, how they do resign with new mobile provisioning profile with out certificate.

I tried for resign commands and I got this.

[Resigning an iOS provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634188/resigning-an-ios-provisioning-profile)

here we need to point certificate in the command. But, I am sure I did not upload certificate file to test flight. Then how they are resigning .ipa file.

any trick/tip please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to resign the application. Application are signed by certificates. Provisional profile is having a list of certificates for which it can allow the permissions for selected devices. You can check it on portal by creating a new provisional profile. You will need to check the certificates.

Now when you want to add new UDIDs, you can just update the provisional profile(PP). Because the PP is already having the reference of the certificate which is used to sign the binary. So there is no need to re-sign the binary.

In short, if you have given a binary to client and he tells to add one more device UDID, no need to generate new binary. Just provide new PP and he will able to install the binary.

Comment: both are treated as binary. if you are packaging your .app file, it becomes .ipa.. there is no such fundamental difference in between this 2..

Comment: SO, we need to install PP first in client device and than we need to install App..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729517/how-to-install-ad-hoc-provisioning-profile-on-tester-device-without-using-itunes

Comment: Can I just unzip and replace embedded.mobileprovision file with new file and again make it .iPA file? Will it works?